# Изменение порядка свойств в объекте JS

Tags: javascript

Есть два сервера, которые используют одну и ту же БД, но имеют разные способы работы к ней.
С первого сервера получаю следующий объект:

```
Object {Id: 1, FIO: "Alex Weston", Address: "16 Wrexham Road", Phone: "077 6102 9187"}
```

Со второго сервера получаю объект с точно такой же информацией, но отличающий расположением поля Id, из-за чего на клиенте неправильно генерируется таблица:

```
Object {FIO: "Alex Weston", Address: "16 Wrexham Road", Phone: "077 6102 9187", Id: 1}
```

Каким образом Id можно передвинуть на первое место?

Comment: каким образом генерируется таблица? Ведь для объекта абсолютно плевать на каком месте ключ находится.. обращаетесь же вы не по позиции, а именно по названию ключа

Comment: Заголовок таблицы генерируется из массива ключей (Object.keys()) объекта в таком порядке, в котором они есть. Данные генерируется перечислением значений объекта по ключу. Объекты могут приходить разные, но Id всегда должно стоять на первом месте

Comment: так возьмите название первой колонки прямо из ключа, а остальные циклом, исключая id..... А почему запрос сервера не может выдать нужный порядок сразу? А если в следующий раз еще что-то в запросах поменяется и вообще все поля будут в разном порядке?

Comment: Вообще полагаться на порядок расположения пар ключ-значение в объекте в JS, мягко говоря, глупо.

Comment: если вы знаете о существовании Object.keys(), то в чем проблема изменить позицию через сортировку